# Dúvida com Git no VsCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, versionamento

estou com problema no meu git no VSCode, consigo `add`, `commitar` e dar `push` normal, mas desde ontem não aparece mais que tenho controle de versionamento no meu VSCode.

[[image: Imagem mostrando tela do Visual Studio Code]
<sup>clique para visualizar em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDzuw.png)

Comment: tenta baixar alguma atualização no plugin do VSCode as vezes tua IDE pode estar desatualizada

Answer (score 0):

No teu perfil do GitHub (ou outro provedor, no caso parece que estava usando o GitLens) vá em:

> *Configurações > Aplicações > Authorized OAuth Apps*, procura por: **GitHub(provedor) for VS Code**

se estiver autorizado você revoka a permissão, por fim você volta na IDE e conecta novamente.

Comment: tá, mas como conecta novamente?

Comment: tem um botão de "Accounts" na canto inferior esquerdo da tela amigo

Comment: estou usando o gitLens pq o outro não aparece.

Comment: Então talvez você precise remover a extensão, procurei pelo ID, é só colar "eamodio.gitlens". Isso porque o vscode já usa o Git padrão como SCM, então pode remover tranquilo

Comment: obrigado amigo, descobri que o problema era no meu pacote git, o git blame estava desabilitado.